# When use my VB 2008 app in Windows 10, it crashes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

When I try to open my VB 2008 application in Windows 10. It crashes. After some debuggin' process I realize that in crashes when I use the new Method of ReportDocument class. Is there any problem when I run the app in Windows 10? If I try to use it in Windows XP or Windows 7, it works

Comment: No one should be using XP anymore. It's been end of life for several years now, and there are several active, unpatched exploits in the wild. It's like trying to use a leaky rowboat and hoping not to get wet.

Comment: Also: make sure the correct CrystalReports runtime is installed on the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Did you installed correctly dependencies of SAP Crystal reports on that machine. Those reports wont work just by putting your application exe

Comment: I'll check if there is a dependecies I was missing. Thanks for your replies